# class not found exception occur when correct class supplied in android

Tags: java, android

This is the code part in my Activity class. This is the `onListItemClick` method. I use String array for enter menu activity classes names. `classes` is the array.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try {
            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.image_and_sound_app."+cheese);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But When i click on a list item exception occur like this

```
nd_sound_app.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.image_and_sound_app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.image_and_sound_app.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.image_and_sound_app.app-2, /system/lib]]
07-09 15:50:14.220    1288-1288/com.example.image_and_sound_app.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-09 15:50:14.220    1288-1288/com.example.image_and_sound_app.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-09 15:50:14.220    1288-1288/com.example.image_and_sound_app.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
```

There is already exist `MainActivity` class. But the exception shows that class not found. How can i solve this ?

Comment: can you post the code of ur classes

Comment: @eldjon this is the declaration of classes `String classes[] = {"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3"};`

Comment: and you are sure that you have such classes as :example1,...  because obviously cant find them

Comment: `com.example.image_and_sound_app.MainActivity` clearly does not exist in the apk.

Comment: That classes not exist but `MainActivity` class already exist. I have tested with `MainActivity` class

Comment: and ur main activity full path is : com.example.image_and_sound_app.MainActivity??

Comment: @njzk2 but that class already exist sir.

Comment: did u try to refresh the project/restart eclise

Comment: @eldjon yh i did that ..

Comment: can u upload the code somewhere.ill try to reproduce it

Comment: can u get it from google drive ?

Comment: @eldjon thanks for ur helping. I have found the working project related to my problem from commented person.

Comment: alright. what was the issue btw?

Answer (score 0):

so u r giving wrong class name. the MainActivity class name is not: com.example.image_and_sound_app.MainActivity.
Double check main activity´s belonging package name.
Cant be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i not use the comment option, my rep is too low. I know how to help you though...

I see that you do the Android-tutorial on buckysroom.

What you write in the comment above is not the declaration of the mainactivity. You only build the Link there to the activity itself.

```
String classes[] = {"MainActivity", "TextPlay", "Email", "Notebook", "example4", "example5", "example6" };
```

This line only is the array where a later code builds a link out of it.

```
 Class ourClass = null;
    try {
        ourClass = Class.forName("com.awo.travistut."+links);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the main class thats missing:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SoundEffectConstants;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDelete);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter = counter+1;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter = counter-1;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

This is the code of the Menu that builds his navigation:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = {"MainActivity", "TextPlay", "Email", "Notebook", "example4", "example5", "example6" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String links = classes[position];

    Class ourClass = null;
    try {
        ourClass = Class.forName("com.awo.travistut."+links);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: what is this `link` variable ?

Comment: Im not sure how to tell him :-) I know what hes missing, i did the same tutorial today. He need the full MainActivity class, thats done in a tutorial before the one i gues he started with.

This is the tutorial: https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6

Comment: ill added the menu class, there you can see how the "link" came.

Comment: @Senchay not clear what are telling .. plz can explain me clearly .. :(

Comment: Ok ill try, sorry. So ill take you do the mentioned tutorial, right? Because its the very same as on buckysroom, if not someone copied it from there. I assume you use that (i see it on the variable Cheese lol :-). If you use that it maybe be best we talk directly somehow, i can give you the project code too if you want, with all classes working.

Comment: wow thats grate .. plz give me that .. yh i take that tutorials :) lol :)

Comment: Here is a fully working example, its at around tutorial step 35 where he implements the Email function. The Navigation works, you can see how the layout of the files should be and check if you have the same.- hope it helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/69uddiig0tp6ovd/TravisTut.rar

Comment: BUT be wanred, i let some things out that i already know and renamed some classes. It maybe be not 100% same as his. Like the cheese variable i named different, for example. But for the most part is the very same.

Comment: If it helped, could you accept the answer please? I wouldnt ask for it, really, but since 50 reputation is needed to make comments i would gladly accept any bit of rep :-) Would really help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why you guys are pulling the workaround to simple problem ? Instead of using reflection, you can do much more efficient and reliable way. This is your code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.image_and_sound_app."+cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Lets assume that classes are:

```
private static final String[] classes = {
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
};
```

and so on. Instead of building classes on the fly, build them in!

```
private static final Class<?>[] classes = {
    A.class,
    B.class,
    C.class
};

...

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); // this line is redundant
    Class<?> ourClass = classes[position];
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
}
```

There is also a good pattern for navigation handling but I do not know if you will get use of it.